# Constructor not working as expected in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create my GridData data in an Update/Awake function as a test. But I can't seem to get my constructor working. I'm new to CSharp and Unity. so, I'm a bit stuck here.

GridData Class

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GridData  {

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct rowData{
        public float[] colum;

    }
    public static int numRows =30;
    public static int numColums =20;
    public rowData[] rows = new rowData[numRows]; 


    //
    //Constructor
    public GridData(int x, int y){
        numRows =y;
        numColums = x;
        rowData[] rows = new rowData[numColums];
    }
}
```

FactalMapData Class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FractalMapData : MonoBehaviour {

    public int gridWidth =20;
    public int gridWHight =20;
    public GridData fractalGrid ;   
    void Update () {

        //TEST
        fractalGrid =new GridData(gridWidth,gridWHight);
        Debug.Log ("row" + fractalGrid.rows.Length); //Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        Debug.Log ("colum" + fractalGrid.rows[0].colum.Length);//Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a basic course in object oriented programming. It will take you a day at most to understand what a class is, what the difference between local and global variables is, when to use static fields etc. Your code shows that you lack the understanding about these things. Allthough you'll eventually solve your problem with trial and error or "learning by doing" it will save you *much* *much* time and frustration if you first gain an understanding of oop. There are lot's of free courses the internet.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha Please don't copy the contents of the post into your edit summary when editing.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in my comment, I advise you to actually *learn* oop before constructing oop code.

But learning by mistakes isn't all that bad, so here the ones you made:

```
[System.Serializable] // not a mistake, but do you really need this?
public class GridData  {

    [System.Serializable] 
    public struct rowData{
        public float[] colum;
    }
    // why are you using a struct with only one field in it
    // do you really need a struct?

    // PITFALL: you'll be wondering later on, why the values for numRows and numColums are the same for all instances
    // Why? Because they are static! That means there are *not* instantiated
    public static int numRows =30;
    public static int numColums =20;

    // You are initializing your rowData here
    // and again in the constructor. What do you actually want?
    public rowData[] rows = new rowData[numRows]; 


    //
    //Constructor
    public GridData(int x, int y){
        // As mentioned before: 
        // you are assigning instantiating values to static fields

        numRows =y;
        numColums = x;

        // you are *defining* a local variable called rows and initializing it with an array of length numColums
        // After we leave the constructor this get's lost
        rowData[] rows = new rowData[numColums];
    }
}
```

Another thing you should think about: Why are you creating a *class*

If you find, that you have a good reason, ask yourself what the responsibility of the class is. E.g.: Should it just hold some data, Does it provide any abstraction, Will it manipulate the data it has, should the data be exposed?

### I think you have not answered most of these questions.

Here is how it *could* work

- "I need a class that holds some grid data"
- "I want the underlying data structure to be a one dimensional array" (for whatever reason)
- "The abstraction is, that the class exposes the data as a two dimensional grid"
- "I don't need to initialize the class with existing data" (for now)

Then you can implement the class

```
 public class GridData {

    // The concrete data doesn't have to be exposed
    // let's make it private
    private float[] data;

    // let's use properties for this (= less code)
    // get; means it's accessible as defined at the beginning (public)
    // private set; means only the class it self can change these numbers
    public int RowCount { get; private set; }
    public int ColCount { get; private set; }

    // I want to represent the data as a 2D grid so let's make a function
    public float GetCell(int x, int y) {
        // validate requests!
        if( 
            x >= ColCount || x < 0
        ||
            y >= RowCount || y < 0
        ) {
            // don't be shy to throw exceptions!
            // they communicate exceptional circumstances!
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Requested cell is not on grid");
        } 

        return data[y * RowCount + x];
    }

    // I want the data to be set from outside
    public float SetCell(int x, int y, float value) {
        // excercise for you!
    }

    public GridData(int cols, int rows) {
        RowCount = rows;
        ColCount = cols;

        this.data = new float[rows * cols];
    }
}
```

Note that there are multiple ways to implement a class that conforms to the needs I formulated.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `public float[] colum;` anywhere in your code.

As a result, when you invoke your constructor, although you correctly create an initialized `rows` array, the `colum` field of each `rowData` instance has not been initialized and will throw a null reference exception when trying to access the length of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
public GridData(int x, int y){
    numRows =y;
    numColums = x;
    rowData[] rows = new rowData[numColums];  // BUG HERE
}
```

Here you are declaring a LOCAL variable `rows`, with the same name as the instance field named `rows`. Thus the instance field `rows` is never assigned.

You mean:

```
public GridData(int x, int y){
    numRows =y;
    numColums = x;
    rows = new rowData[numColums];
}
```